# Issue with table content not visible

Tags: java, javafx

I have the following Node creator in my Java application:

```
private Node createWelcomePane() {
    HBox hbox_accounts = new HBox();
    this.getAccounts();
    tableAccounts.setPrefSize(500,500);
    final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));
    tableAccounts.setEditable(false);
    TableColumn idCol = new TableColumn("ID");
    idCol.setMinWidth(100);
    idCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Account, Integer>("id"));

    TableColumn typeCol = new TableColumn("Account Type");
    typeCol.setMinWidth(100);
    typeCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Account, String>("type"));

    TableColumn balanceCol = new TableColumn("Balance");
    balanceCol.setMinWidth(200);
    balanceCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Account, Float>("balance"));

    tableAccounts.setItems(accountList);
    tableAccounts.getColumns().addAll(idCol, typeCol, balanceCol);
    hbox_accounts.getChildren().add(tableAccounts);
    hbox_accounts.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    return hbox_accounts;
}
```

Which is fine - it creates table. However, table does not have any data in it (however, I can click on first 4 rows - because I have 4 entires in my array).Any ideas why data is not visible?

Answer (score -1):

I found out that I had to add getters and setters to my Account class.

Case solved!